# Testing clojure with kerodon

Tags: clojure, luminus, selmer

I'm testing a clojure luminus/selmer application with kerodon. 
I'm getting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field could not be found with selector "[:#name]"` when trying to access an input field with `id=name` as follows:

```
(deftest home
  (-> (session app)
      (visit "/")
      (fill-in [:#name] "Peter")
      (fill-in [:#age] "25")
      (press "Sign up!")
      (within [:h1]
              (has (text? "Hello Peter 25")))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using text value of label for input field, `fill-in` accepts text value of label as well as id of elem you need to fill. Refer to the [kerodon](https://github.com/xeqi/kerodon/blob/7c65de7a97f6a5a1a1c8f83e5ed6378cf5858c5c/test/kerodon/unit/core.clj#L311) source, there are tests for both label value and selector.

For example:-

```
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="name"\>
```

You can write

```
(deftest home 
   (-> (session app) 
       (visit "/") 
       (fill-in "Name" "Peter")
        ...))
```

Comment: It is still not working. Or is it that kerodon works only with hiccup?    

<form action="/log" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <label for="age">Age</label>
    <input type="text" id="age">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>

(deftest login
  (-> (session app)
      (visit "/log")
      (fill-in "Name" "Peter")
      (fill-in "Age" "25")
      (press "Submit")
      (within [:h1]
        (has (text? "Hello Peter 25")))))

Comment: It doesn't really matter what template you're using. Tests are run on browser-like flow when there's pure HTML. Are other fields throwing the same exception?